# Establishing Android network connectivity after a long period of device inactivity

Tags: android, android-networking, user-inactivity

My application forwards SMS' to an email address. One big problem is the first message of the day. The device (Attrix set in maximum battery saving mode) is in a deep sleep. The SMS is received normally, but there is no network/data connectivity until I wake up the phone by hand, which is very inelegant.

I'd like to request/force/trick Android into awakening its networking, and permit connections. I have a CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE listener, so the app can detect when this happens asynchronously.

Currently, HttpClient.execute() says "Connection to http://xxx.yyy.com refused". This is called immediately after the SMS is received. This is attempted without any isConnected() checks, which do say "false". I was hoping the request would provoke the networking to wake up.

I have also tried (note - no experience with this method)

connectivityManager.startUsingNetworkFeature(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE, "enableHIPRI");

but the code just ... stops ... there. No errors, exceptions, logs, its just stops. I cannot even check the return value.

I have not tried wake locks, since they seem to be about waking up CPUs (CPU seems OK) and screens (don't care).

In a previous version of my app, I went a different route. I have a TimerTask that tries every 5 minutes, until the message is sent  successfully (i.e. Javax Mail transport.send() does not throw MessagingException). It completely disregards any information on the current network state. This seems to work very reliably. But this is throwing darts in the dark, and I am sure it can be improved.

Thanks!

PVS